# Why doesn't English have a word that means both Hello and Goodbye?

Tags: history

Multiple languages, including some from which England draws its words, have words that mean both "Hello" and "Goodbye":

- French - Salut!
- Italian - Ciao!
- Hawaiian - Aloha!
- German (Austrian) - Servus!

I understand that the answer might be simply "It just doesn't", but is there any history here? Was there such a word that fell out of favour?

Comment: 'Good morning' is used for both, and sometimes 'Good afternoon', but these are obviously not always applicable..

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - "Good to see you," works for coming and going, AND covers all times of day.

Comment: Why does English have to have a word that means both hello and goodbye? "Nice to meet you" is used when greeting and saying goodbye. Do other languages have the same phrase? The Spanish word for hello is "hola" and I don't think it is used for goodbye.

Comment: 'Hello; I must be leaving!' [Groucho Marx] works for both _at the same time_. Other languages probably don't have _this_ facility.

Comment: Why doesn't English have a word for "*[disrespecting one's eldest half-sister by referring to her husband as girly-girl-manly-boy though he's amused but the rest of the family isn't](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4732/55623)*"?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth It's a very long time since I heard anyone use either "Good morning" or "good afternoon" at parting. The first time I took my driving test, in 1962, I failed. And I will always remember the examiner's parting words, which were *good-day*. I don't think I have heard anyone use it since.

Comment: Good day, sir. I said good day!

Comment: Because, presumably, speakers of the language didn't find it particularly useful.

Comment: @JohnClifford - just noticed your comment. I'll be happy to delete my answer if you convert your comment into one.

Comment: Regarding comments as to why English should or should not have such a word: it's simply that at least 3 languages that have significantly informed the English language *do* have such a word. For English *not* to have such a word (if that were the case) might be the result of some interesting history... or not... that's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: Less tongue-in-cheek, since there are uncountably infinite concepts for which English doesn't have a single word or even a concise phrase, it's probably more logical to turn the question around and ask why those other languages *do* have a word for hello-goodbye. Do all those words in the other languages share any kind of etymological relationship? If not, what *do* the words or language have in common with each other, but not with English? Once we isolate that, we can ask *why* English didn't share that particular history.

Comment: @DanBron: I think that's a fair point, however, I had hoped that the fact that 3 of the 4 examples I gave are from languages that have a close etymological relationship with English and that the concept of a word meaning both Hello and Goodbye is not an obscure concept by any stretch of the imagination or of Google would be enough to separate this from the general morass of "please give me a word that means this weirdly specific and obscure thing" that exists in EL&U.

Comment: @Dancrumb I agree with you, and I was particularly impressed by the final sentence of your question (and subsequent comments) which indicated to everyone why you thought there *should* be such a word, which immediately separated it from the pack of "weirdly specific SWRs", as you put it. I like your question. I'm just suggesting a way of asking it that might prove more fruitful.

Comment: Old English had *Wes þū hāl!* (or *Wes hāl!*). Reference: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Old_English/The_spoken_language

Comment: @BiscuitBoy Don't worry about it, mine was more of a joke based on the meme than an attempt at an answer, I'm happy to leave this one in your capable hands. I'll even give you an upvote! :D

Comment: _shalom_ in Hebrew also fits this category.

Comment: Would the quality of our lives be incomparably better if we had such a word?

Comment: The direction of this question is problematic. You could just as easily ask from the other side why those other languages don't have separate words for meeting and parting. Or why Spanish had gender on nouns but English doesn't, or why English bothers with past and future tense markers when all you have to do is say yesterday or later. All you can really do is describe here, English has this and doesn't have that and when (possibly) it happened and maybe if there are some socioeconomic events that are contemporary. Even with phonetics it's problematic to say people are lazy.

Comment: @Mitch, but all of those are interesting questions and if people are curious as to the answer, they could ask them here, right?

Comment: @Dancrumb Yes, they are interesting questions but any kind of 'why' question is going to be very speculative and therefore of questionable fit on a Q/A site like ELU (it's like "Why have you stopped beating your wife?", very leading). I'm suggesting that instead of "Why doesn't..." it be "Does..." and "... are there reasons for having a single word or two?" in order to elicit a good answer.

Comment: @JohnClifford The fact that your comment reads as a brusque departure rather belies your attempt to use it as an ironic answer. Outside of the parts of Australia catering to tourists, it simply isn't a greeting any more.

Comment: @BenL *shalom*, *ciao*, *aloha*, and *salut* in English do as well.

Comment: @lly Hence me pointing out in March last year that my comment was a joke based on a meme. Thanks for the anniversary reminder, though! XD

Comment: Salutations, while normally a greeting, can be used to acknowledge someone's departure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably, [***good day***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/good-day) is the English equivalent, although a bit old fashioned.

> used as a ​greeting or when saying ​goodbye during the day

[Cambridge Online]

Comment: Nah, unless it's clipped and in an Australian accent, the greeting sense of *good day* is archaic to the point of obsolescence. Even with altered phrasing, people are going to take it as a more-or-less ironic farewell.

Answer (score 3):

- English - Ciao!

> ciao  interj.
>
> Used to express greeting or farewell.

[[American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. Copyright © 2011](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ciao)]

English continues to borrow words from said languages.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought. Ciao is an English word now...

Comment: The OP already acknowledges that English takes some of those words from other languages so I'm not sure this helps much. Good point nonetheless!

Comment: It's not in common usage and on the rare occasions that it is used it's almost exclusively used as a farewell. A native English speaker greeting you with "ciao" would be extremely unusual.

Comment: @JohnClifford This answer is as creative as the question. This answer shows that English is a melting pot for all the languages in the world.

Comment: The fact that it's in AHDEL means that the usage is appreciable (they don't include very rare usages); the fact that they include the 'greeting' sense shows that it is used, @Michael.

Comment: In NYC Ciao could only mean bye ; but don't try it uptown after Columbia...
& I wonder how could you be welcome in OKLAHOMA with a ciao :)

Comment: @DAVE  Well...as an Okie, it depends on who you say it to. I'd actually propose that if we are just going to put forth loan words as answers, I hear "Aloha" more here in Oklahoma than "Ciao". I'd imagine the effect gets more pronounced as you go west. "Aloha" at least has the advantage that it is used much more by English speakers than by those of the donating language.

Comment: I agree with U TED as I was about to say the same concerning "Aloha" (In NY, we'd more use Ciao than Aloha). But I'm glad an Okie tells me you hear more Aloha than Ciao (I've nothing against OK). I'm sure it's the same in AL.

Comment: "Aloha" is also common here in Hawaii (which, as some may not realize, is part of the US).

Comment: We do know. It's the Island near Porto Rico :O)

Comment: Ciao is well used in Melbourne (Australia), which has a significant post-War Italian population; and in the more affluent, well-educated and well-traveled suburbs even ciao as a greeting would be understood, if not often used. Its use would be less in the smaller cities, and you would definitely get strange looks if you used it (even to say goodbye) at a rural town corner store.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your original question, English has many words that mean or have meant both hello and goodbye. They're not in common use because, well, English has *many* words.

The benefit of being a compound of German, French, Latin, and whatever else might wander into a dimly lit alley is that English can be precise about what's being said.

You're going to see *ciao* and *aloha* and *shalom* and *salut* and *cheerio* all over but, unless the person is wearing their Italian/Hawaiian/Jewish/French/Dickensian ethnicity on their sleeves, those expressions are going to be limited to Italian/Hawaiian/Jewish/French/Dickensian contexts or allusions.